# center float elements

Tags: html, css

```css
.key {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.clearFloat {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="keyWrap">
  <div class="key"><span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="key">2</div>
  <div class="key">3</div>

  <div class="clearFloat"></div>

  <div class="key">4</div>
  <div class="key">5</div>
  <div class="key">6</div>
  <div class="clearFloat"></div>

  <div class="key">0</div>
</div>
```

How can I make the number center center within the circle? I can't do padding or margin because it will be responsive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `line-height`

```css
.key {
  line-height:40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.clearFloat {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="keyWrap">
  <div class="key"><span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="key">2</div>
  <div class="key">3</div>

  <div class="clearFloat"></div>

  <div class="key">4</div>
  <div class="key">5</div>
  <div class="key">6</div>
  <div class="clearFloat"></div>

  <div class="key">0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is, you can use `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle`. And it is Responsive also. 
And one thing is that If you change height then also it will stay vertically middle. Also You can use `line-height` but will change when you increase height of your circle.

Use it like following:

```css
.key {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display:table;
}
.clearFloat {
  clear: both;
}

.key > span{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
```

```html
<div class="keyWrap">
  <div class="key"><span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="key"><span>2</span></div>
  <div class="key"><span>3</span></div>

  <div class="clearFloat"></div>

  <div class="key"><span>4</span></div>
  <div class="key"><span>5</span></div>
  <div class="key"><span>6</span></div>
  <div class="clearFloat"></div>

  <div class="key"><span>0</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I stretch the circle to fit the parent's width?

Comment: How you want to stretch the circle?

Comment: I found a way, here http://jsfiddle.net/5adjhd1x/ but how can I make spaces between them? I'm actually try to mimic iphone unlock password screen.

Comment: u use width 30% and margin 5px, can it fully filled the screen?

Comment: You can adjust using developer tools like firebug. But it not make responsive. for that you have to use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give padding at top

```css
.key {
  width: 40px;
padding-top:10px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.clearFloat {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="keyWrap">
  <div class="key"><span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="key">2</div>
  <div class="key">3</div>

  <div class="clearFloat"></div>

  <div class="key">4</div>
  <div class="key">5</div>
  <div class="key">6</div>
  <div class="clearFloat"></div>

  <div class="key">0</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its been specificaly mentioned that you can't use padding and now you are using it here..

Answer (score 0):

solution1: `line-height`

```css
.key {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
}
.clearFloat {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="keyWrap">
  <div class="key"><span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="key">2</div>
  <div class="key">3</div>

  <div class="clearFloat"></div>

  <div class="key">4</div>
  <div class="key">5</div>
  <div class="key">6</div>
  <div class="clearFloat"></div>

  <div class="key">0</div>
</div>
```

solution2: `flex`

```css
.key {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.clearFloat {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="keyWrap">
  <div class="key"><span>1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="key">2</div>
  <div class="key">3</div>

  <div class="clearFloat"></div>

  <div class="key">4</div>
  <div class="key">5</div>
  <div class="key">6</div>
  <div class="clearFloat"></div>

  <div class="key">0</div>
</div>
```